# How disable scanning @Configuration class in Spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, configuration

I have two Spring Boot applications which depend on the same `common` module. In the `common` module, I have two Configuration `classes` for two different DB. In the first app, I need to have a connection on the 2 DB but in the second app is not necessary to have a connection on 2 DB and I want to have a connection only on the first DB.

My second app by default scanning the whole `common` module and `Configuration` for two `DB`. I want to disable scanning on the second `Configuration`.  How can I do that?

This is my second app :

```java
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com" })
    @EnableScheduling
    public class secondApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(secondApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

First configuration:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresqlEntityManagers", 
            transactionManagerRef = "postgresqlTransactionManager", 
            basePackages = "com.db1")
    public class firstConfiguration {
```

Second Configuration:

```java
        @Configuration
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        @EnableJpaRepositories(
                entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresqlEntityManagers", 
                transactionManagerRef = "postgresqlTransactionManager", 
                basePackages = "com.db2")
        public class secondConfiguration {
```

Comment: Use ComponentScan with an exclude filter. See the javadoc for details.

Comment: Do you jave any example?

Comment: No. I could write one. But by reading the documentation, you could write one too (and learn more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code, you add a `@ComponnentScan` and use `excludeFilters` in order to to exclude any classes you want and also exclude it from auto configuration data sources by using this `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which has exclude field. by following these configurations, you should have an example as this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.project",
         excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                classes = {AnyCustomConnectionProvider.class, AnyCustomJpaConfiguration.class}))
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                                    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.